# fileName or filename?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parameter naming:  filename or fileName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742115/parameter-naming-filename-or-filename)

What do you use - filename or fileName? The classes in the JDK use a lower case 'n', e.g. FilenameFilter, so, for consistency, I do too. But the correct way, I believe, should be fileName (as in C#).

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742115/parameter-naming-filename-or-filename Also: trivial and subjective.

Comment: sorry, did not come up in my search! I have voted to close.

Comment: The "duplicate" is asking about the general practice, this question about Java. There *can* be differences.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'd base that decision on the surrounding identifiers.

If `filename` is the only identifier regarding files in its context, I'd stay with that.

Example:

```
public void load(String filename) { ... }
```

But as soon as you have other file attributes I'd consider using this:

```
private String fileName;
private long fileSize
private DateTime fileAge;
```

Comment: This makes no sense. You start with single field called filename. And a few weeks later you add fileSize. Then you need to rename the old field.

Answer (score 10):

my dictionary says "filename" so i'd keep using a lowercase "n": http://dict.leo.org/?search=filename

Comment: Great to have a link to a good dictionary. I always want to camelize according to the actual spelling. The hard thing is usually to find the correct spelling. Leo says "filename", so that's it. Leo also says "field name", which is great because I always spell it "fieldName".

Answer (score 8):

The real question is whether the thing is called "file name" or "filename".
The rest is then a trivial matter.

The Wikipedia article is [filename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename), even though the content has both "file name" and "filename".

Personally I vote for "filename".

Answer (score 4):

**filename**

Like you, I do it to be consistent with the Java libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really consistent, but I tend to use "filename", even though fileName would be more grammatically correct since "file name" is two words, not one.